# Why electrons get excited?

Tags: electrons, atoms

Why and how are electrons get excited and what happen inside an atom when electrons get excited?

Comment: Hi! Just a matter of nomenclature: it is more correct to say [excited atoms][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state] rather than excited electrons, because, since electrons do not have any internal sub-structure and they are always the same, it has no sense to talk about their excitations.

Comment: pleas tell me more about it(excited atom).

Comment: wikipedia is too scientific.

Comment: Well, let me try to simplify it as much as possible! An atom is a compound state of a nucleus and one or more electrons. This system has a certain amount of energy; one kind of energy is that of the electrons which revolve around the nucleus. There exists a state, called ground states, in which this energy is the smallest. Also there exist some other states where the electrons revolve faster or farther from the nucleus; in these states, the energy of the electrons (and the atom on the whole) is higher. These are called excited states (of the atom).

Comment: @AstoundingJB The further the electron is from the nucleus, the slower the speed.  For example in the Bohr model, speed is inversely proportional to energy level.  The ground state has the fastest speed.

Comment: You're right Dave, my mistake! The **closer** the electrons, the fastest the speed! Anyway, I think that the ground state has the **slowest** speed (and it is the farthest, as you correctly pointed out!)!

Comment: ground state in the closest and fastest.  See equations 10 and 11 here: http://www.pha.jhu.edu/~rt19/hydro/node2.html

Comment: check (my) answer on [similar question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129281/what-is-quantum-jump-of-an-electron/129287#129287)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an atom, an electron can only have energies of a certain discrete set of values. These values are referred to as "energy levels".  For this reason it is said that energy levels are quantizied.

To go from a lower level to a higher level, a photon matching the energy difference between the energy levels is absorbed.

When the electron changes energy levels, the wave-function of the electron changes.  For example, the probability distribution of where the electron is located in the atom changes.  Generally, the higher the energy level, the greater the probability that the electron will be located further away from the nucleus.