# What is Quantum jump of an electron?

Tags: electrons, atoms

Can any one define quantum jump 9 quantities jump of an electron ? 
I know it it is a silly question but can anyone please explain me in detail.I am a  learning about the structure of atom  and I want some help. 
Can anyone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron's quantum jump is the same thing as an atomic electron transition.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_electron_transition

At the beginning, the electron has one energy and sits at some level which may be represented by some "typical distance" from the nucleus.

At the end, it has another value of the energy, so a different "typical distance from the nucleus".

Quantum mechanics, the theory of atoms etc., implies that not all values of energy but only some particular values are allowed. This is why the electron can't gradually slowly walk or creep from one energy (or one orbit) to another. It has to "jump" i.e. omit all the values in between. It directly changes from one level of energy to another, i.e. by absurbing a photon to obey the energy conservation law.

Energy jumps are behind the emission and absorption of light by atoms.

To learn everything about the jumps and why the energy levels are discrete etc., one needs to learn quantum mechanics.

Comment: If you weren't Luboš Motl I'd say that this answer is wrong, but I'll at least say that I don't understand what you mean by it. Unitary evolution is continuous, and that includes energy level transitions. The "quantum jump" is a concept from the Bohr model, pre-QM, and has been obsolete since the 1920s. There's no rule in QM that a particle can't be in a superposition of eigenstates of different energies, and the excited states are not energy eigenstates anyway once you allow the possibility of emitting a photon.

Comment: Dear @benrg, be sure that the term "quantum jump" is being used even in the new full quantum mechanics, see the first paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_electron_transition - not just in Bohr's theory. Concerning Bohr's theory, it was a toy model for quantum mechanics and some things were supposed to be analogous to what they are in the full QM theory but it never quite worked. ... Otherwise in QM, unitary evolution is mathematically continuous but the actual observables such as energy often evolve discontinuously. They have to 'cause levels in between discrete ones don't exist.

Comment: A particle is generally in a superposition of eigenstates of a given operator, also in a general superposition of energy eigenstates, but it doesn't mean that the energy is in between. It means that the energy is *either* one eigenvalue *or* another. ... Right, if a state ultimately emits a photon, it is not a stationary state, an energy eigenstate. But the deviation from its being an energy state (the imaginary part of the energy of the quasinormal mode) may often be extremely tiny and negligible relatively to the real part, ...

Comment: so it is extremely important to know how to solve the approximate problem where the excited state *is* exactly stationary (an energy eigenstate) and be able to add the interaction with the electromagnetic field (allowing the emission) as a small perturbation.

Comment: I don't see how the electron energy can be said to evolve discontinuously. At what time does it suddenly change? The expectation value evolves continuously. You might as well say that a [natural trumpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_trumpet) can only occupy discrete harmonic states and "classically jumps" between them. That could be a useful approximation for some purposes, but it isn't what's happening physically. It's a continuous system that happens to have an approximate decomposition into discrete harmonics.

Comment: @benrg The existence of quantum jumps is an experimental fact. [This standard review](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9702007) on the topic has a more detailed explanation, and a list of references. The existence of discontinuous jumps is intimately connected with the discontinuous measurement process, therefore your intuition about continuous unitary evolution is not quite appropriate.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison, if Luboš was talking about wavefunction collapse then that might explain our disagreement, but I'm pretty sure he was talking about unitary evolution, and I know I was.

Comment: Dear @benrg, the wave function evolves continuously (and unitarily) but the energy - or any other observable - is not a function or a functional of the wave function. Instead, the probability distributions for the different values of energy - or any other observable - may be computed from the wave function. One may get these probabilities but they're still probabilities of allowed values, i.e. eigenvalues, and they're discrete with nothing in between. So the wave function may change gradually from (0,1) to (1,0) for the two lowest-lying states but that doesn't mean that...

Comment: the energy is changing continuously. It means that there is an increasing probability that the energy discontinuously jumps. Whether it has jumped may only be revealed by a measurement and quantum mechanics predicts the probability for the energy to jump. But quantum mechanics also predicts or implies, and experiments confirm, that the energy is never found anywhhere in the middle.

Comment: @LubošMotl, if you replace the two energy levels with spin-up and spin-down, you could make the same argument: there are no intermediate values of spin along the z axis, so the spin does not change continuously from +z to -z, there is merely an increasing probability that it will suddenly jump from +z to -z. In this case the argument is obviously silly because all of the intermediate states are points on the Bloch sphere representing intermediate spins. With the two energy levels there is less symmetry, but this is still a rotation in a Hilbert space, and you could pick a different basis.

Comment: No, it is not silly. The situations are indeed absolutely analogous, like any other situation in QM. There is no intermediate value of $j_z$ between $-\hbar/2$ and $+\hbar/2$. There are pure states where the spin is sharply polarized with respect to another axis different from $+z$ or $-z$ but these states don't have a well-defined $j_z$, they are not eigenstates. If you ask what is their $j_z$, it is either $+1/2$ or $-1/2$ with some odds but nothing in between.

Comment: My point was that every point on the Bloch sphere is equivalent to every other under rotational symmetry. They are all eigenstates of spin in some direction. If you choose to measure along the z axis then you get ±½, but why did you make that choice? Likewise, why not choose a basis corresponding to an intermediate state of the energy level transition? My description of this process is basis independent; yours isn't.

Comment: Yes, all axes are physically equally good by the rotational symmetry. The choice of the $z$ in so many cases is a pure convention. The possible values of $j_z$ are $\pm 1/2$ and nothing in between. Exactly because of rotational symmetry, the very same statement holds for the projection $j_a$ with respect to any other axis $a$. There is never any allowed value in between. All my statements are basis-independent - they may be described in any basis - but of course, sometimes I am talking about vectors that form a rather natural basis by themselves; the claims still may be said in other bases.

Comment: Otherwise I agree that your statements are basis-independent. They are equally wrong in *all* bases (and in all applications and for observables with a discrete spectrum in physics), too. It reminds me of Zwicky's definition of spherical bastards who are bastards regardless of the direction from which they are looked at.

Comment: @benrg I thought the discussion was about whether the *energy* changes continuously, not the wave function. In my opinion, as soon as you ask how an observable quantity changes, you are implicitly asking a question about measurement. How else could one talk about observables? The question about how the energy of an individual atomic system evolves can only be answered by continuously measuring the atom *in its energy eigenbasis* (approximately), in which case the quantum jumps are seen. One could choose any other basis, but then one doesn't learn about the energy, but some other observable(s).

Answer (score 0):

(add my comment as an answer)

It all depends on the **time-energy uncertainty relation** 
$$ (\Delta t) (\Delta E) \ge ℏ/2 $$
(see for example [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html) and [here](http://ocw.usu.edu/physics/classical-mechanics/pdf_lectures/14.pdf)).

Classicaly a particle can **access only system (energy) states which are compatible with its (current) energy**. Actually this **is still true in quantum mechanics**, the difference is the time-energy uncertainty which provides a twist if you like.

A particle can transition to another (energy) state by a change of its energy. Due to the uncertainty relation, given a (small) time-frame, some energy can be *given* so to say, to the particle, so the jump to another state (which was *classicaly unlikely*) is now possible and can happen. Of course this works both ways.